# Water pooling against the garage, limited drainage options

Tags: drainage, landscaping, frost-heave

I have a single family home in the city in MN. My detached garage abuts the alley, and I have a concrete slab next to it that spans the rest of my small property line (basically the back of my property is either covered by concrete or the garage.)

The issue I’m having is that the water draining away from my property to the alley is getting trapped along the garage. (The garage appears to be low on one corner because water will seep under the door a little ways). The fence posts around this spot have also started to be affected by frost-heaves. Either I have to raise the garage (really out of the question), lower the entire section of concrete next to the garage, or something else to get the water draining freely out to the alley, or at least not pooling against the garage.

There is no open ground to dig a French drain without tearing up concrete... I’m wondering if this group has any other ideas. Could it be something as easy as digging a low spot in my yard a few feet away from the garage, and planting a rain garden and have the water collect there in the spring instead of against my garage?

Comment: Some pictures would really help. You mention that the back of your property is covered in impervious materials but then talk about frost heaves and adding a rain garden. It sounds like you might have some options.

Comment: Will add pictures, yea, tough to paint a picture with just words.

Comment: i modded an AC condensation pump to act as a mini-sump pump that needs little-to-no pit; something like that might work for you; just drill holes in the collection tank on the bottom so as to allow outside water into the chamber.